# Python objects in my ArcMap addIn aren't instantiated

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-addin

I've got a weird problem.  My addin throws problems intermittently where it doesn't recognize buttons or tools when I try to toggle the visibility in my code.  It seems as though the objects aren't instantiated as trying to toggle them works after I try to interact with them.  What is the problem and how do I begin to debug it?  My code is far too long to post but if there's something I can provide to help can you let me know?

Here's a scenario:

User starts Arc and clicks a button.  The button tries to enable another button with:

```
anotherButton.enabled = False
```

Arc throws an error:

```
global variable "anotherButton" not defined.
```

User clicks on "anotherButton" and then tries the first button again.  This time the command executes and "anotherButton" is disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The add-in framework usually won't create the objects until it needs them. I have [a solution in this Esri forums thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/87894-Python-Add-in-puzzler-with-menus-on-a-toolbar): create them yourself at load time, so you'd have something like

```
anotherButton = anotherButtonClass()
```

at the bottom of your add-in's main `.py` file to make sure it's around.

Comment: wow!  Thank you.  I can't tell you how many hours I scoured the internet looking for this solution.

Comment: @Jason Is this behavior similar to the "onDemand" property of .NET add-in types? I would generally set "onDemand" to false to avoid such problems.

Comment: Exactly the same. The Python add-in framework shares a lot of the same code with the .Net add-in framework.